# Problem implementing cipher in downloader library in android

Tags: java, android, encryption

I'm using [this library](https://github.com/tonyofrancis/Fetch) in my project to download files and it's working great. Now I want that the documents and videos I download must be encrypted.
This is the code I managed to write after some research. But it's giving a download error.

```
 public static class MyStorageResolver extends DefaultStorageResolver {
        String ALGORITHM = "Blowfish";
        String MODE = "Blowfish/CBC/PKCS5Padding";
        String IV = "!a3edr45";
        String KEY = "xxxxxxxx";
        Cipher cipher;

        public MyStorageResolver(Context context) {
            super(context, FetchCoreUtils.getFileTempDir(context));
        }


        @NotNull
        @Override

        public OutputResourceWrapper getRequestOutputResourceWrapper(@NotNull Downloader.ServerRequest request) {
            try {
                Key secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(KEY.getBytes(), ALGORITHM);
                cipher = Cipher.getInstance(MODE);
                cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, new IvParameterSpec(IV.getBytes()));

                return new OutputResourceWrapper() {
                    RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(request.getFile(), "rw");

                    @Override
                    public void write(@NotNull byte[] byteArray, int offSet, int length) throws IOException {
                        randomAccessFile.write(cipher.update(byteArray, offSet, length), offSet, length);
                        Log.d("download", "raf writing");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void setWriteOffset(long offset) throws IOException {
                        int AES_BLOCK_SIZE = 16;
                        int skip = (int) (offset % AES_BLOCK_SIZE);
                        long blockOffset = offset - skip;
                        long numberOfBlocks = blockOffset / AES_BLOCK_SIZE;

                        BigInteger ivForOffsetAsBigInteger = new BigInteger(1, IV.getBytes()).add(BigInteger.valueOf(numberOfBlocks));
                        byte[] ivForOffsetByteArray = ivForOffsetAsBigInteger.toByteArray();
                        IvParameterSpec computedIvParameterSpecForOffset;
                        if (ivForOffsetByteArray.length < AES_BLOCK_SIZE) {
                            byte[] resizedIvForOffsetByteArray = BigInteger.valueOf(AES_BLOCK_SIZE).toByteArray();
                            System.arraycopy(ivForOffsetByteArray, 0, resizedIvForOffsetByteArray, AES_BLOCK_SIZE - ivForOffsetByteArray.length, ivForOffsetByteArray.length);
                            computedIvParameterSpecForOffset = new IvParameterSpec(resizedIvForOffsetByteArray);
                        } else {
                            computedIvParameterSpecForOffset = new IvParameterSpec(ivForOffsetByteArray, ivForOffsetByteArray.length - AES_BLOCK_SIZE, AES_BLOCK_SIZE);
                        }
                        try {
                            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, computedIvParameterSpecForOffset);
                        } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException | InvalidKeyException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        byte[] skipBuffer = BigInteger.valueOf(skip).toByteArray();
                        try {
                            cipher.update(skipBuffer, 0, skip, skipBuffer);
                        } catch (ShortBufferException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        randomAccessFile.seek(offset);

                        Log.d("download", "raf seeked");

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void flush() {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void close() throws IOException {
                        randomAccessFile.close();
                    }
                };
            } catch (FileNotFoundException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException | NoSuchPaddingException e) {
                Log.d("download", "raf error");

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return super.getRequestOutputResourceWrapper(request);
        }

    }
```

I'm initializing fetch like this

```
        FetchConfiguration fetchConfiguration = new FetchConfiguration.Builder(this)
                .setDownloadConcurrentLimit(2)
                .enableRetryOnNetworkGain(true)
//                .setNamespace("TdeskDownloader")
                .enableFileExistChecks(true)
                .setProgressReportingInterval(500)
                .setAutoRetryMaxAttempts(3)
                .setNotificationManager(new DefaultFetchNotificationManager(this) {

                    @Override
                    public void updateNotification(@NotNull NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder, @NotNull DownloadNotification downloadNotification, @NotNull Context context) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), DownloadsActivity.class);
                        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                        notificationBuilder
                                .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
                                .setColorized(true)
                                .setNotificationSilent()
                                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                                .setAutoCancel(true)
                                .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent))
                                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round))
                                .setBadgeIconType(NotificationCompat.BADGE_ICON_SMALL);

                        super.updateNotification(notificationBuilder, downloadNotification, context);
                    }

                    @NotNull
                    @Override
                    public Fetch getFetchInstanceForNamespace(@NotNull String namespace) {
                        return fetch;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean shouldCancelNotification(@NotNull DownloadNotification downloadNotification) {
                        return downloadNotification.getStatus() == Status.CANCELLED;
                    }
                })
                .setHttpDownloader(new HttpUrlConnectionDownloader(Downloader.FileDownloaderType.PARALLEL))
                .setStorageResolver(new MyStorageResolver(this.getApplicationContext()))
                .build();
        Fetch.Impl.setDefaultInstanceConfiguration(fetchConfiguration);

        fetch = Fetch.Impl.getDefaultInstance();
```

this is the error log:

```
2021-07-10 04:19:15.724 E/LibGlobalFetchLib: FileDownloader download:DownloadInfo(id=-1757988576, namespace='LibGlobalFetchLib', url='https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/10/file-example_PDF_500_kB.pdf', file='/storage/emulated/0/Download/tdesk/file-example_PDF_500_kB.pdf', group=0, priority=HIGH, headers={}, downloaded=0, total=469513, status=DOWNLOADING, error=NONE, networkType=ALL, created=1625870930995, tag=null, enqueueAction=UPDATE_ACCORDINGLY, identifier=0, downloadOnEnqueue=true, extras={"mime":"application\/pdf"}, autoRetryMaxAttempts=0, autoRetryAttempts=3, etaInMilliSeconds=-1, downloadedBytesPerSecond=-1)
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: src.length=8 srcPos=0 dst.length=1 dstPos=8 length=8
    at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
    at com.toppersdesk.app.commonUtility$MyStorageResolver$1.setWriteOffset(commonUtility.java:366)
    at com.tonyodev.fetch2.downloader.ParallelFileDownloaderImpl.downloadSliceFiles(ParallelFileDownloaderImpl.kt:416)
    at com.tonyodev.fetch2.downloader.ParallelFileDownloaderImpl.run(ParallelFileDownloaderImpl.kt:149)
    at com.tonyodev.fetch2.downloader.DownloadManagerImpl$start$$inlined$synchronized$lambda$1.run(DownloadManagerImpl.kt:103)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Maybe I'm doing some basic mistake related to class. Can someone please help point me to where I'm doing mistakes in the code?

**Edit:** I'm following [the example in this issue](https://github.com/tonyofrancis/Fetch/issues/470) for implementing the resume-supported cipher encryption. I have never worked with this class so I don't know exactly what's the issue with the logic provided in example code.

Comment: [1] If the key is in your source code (as in, your app can decrypt this stuff without the input of a key by the user or interaction with the secure enclave on the phone __it doesn't count__. It's like locking your front door with an extremely excellent and expensive lock and hiding the key under the mat. That has 'the key is below this mat' printed on it. [2] Include the error you get. The whole stack trace.

Comment: @rzwitserloot You are right but this is just initial implementation for encryption. Once its working fine I'll implement any secure way to store the key. I have included the error log. Please check.

Comment: The error message explains itself, no? You're invoking `System.arraycopy` with nonsensical values. Debug as normal (print the values, check with what you think they should have been, there will be a mismatch, now you know where to look).

Comment: @rzwitserloot I already know from the error that it's some issue with System.arraycopy but I really don't have any idea about the logic used in code. I'm following [the example in this issue](https://github.com/tonyofrancis/Fetch/issues/470) for implementing the resume-supported cipher encryption. I have never worked with this class so I don't know exactly what's the issue with the logic provided in example code.

Comment: You can't honestly expect to debug code you don't understand. Somebody wrote this; if it's buggy, ask them to fix it. If you're adapting code you don't understand, that's a doomed exercise, you'd need to understand it first. Your questions should be about the part you don't understand, not about the part that is throwing the error; assume there are about 100 further errors behind this error. Now realize that asking 100 SO questions is going to burn a lot of bridges and take half a year.